# Get value selected CheckBox in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working width checkBox, for the example there are 3 color options and 2 options of placement in the form of CheckBox, the problem is that if I want to choose 2 options for example: party and red only shows me in the alert one of the two and not altogether as it should be.

try to validate that option as shown in code but it did not work and I do not think it is a good option because it would be very long considering the number of options that the user could choose.

how can I get the two options the user chose in a good way?

thanks

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  
    this.state = {
      checkRed:false,
    checkWhite:false,
    checkPurpura:false,
    checkParty:false,
    checkMaarriage:false,
   
    };
    }
    
    checkBoxRed(){
    
      this.setState({ checkRed: !this.state.checkRed,id:"red" });
    }
    checkBoxWhite(){
    
      this.setState({ checkWhite: !this.state.checkWhite,id:"white" });
    }
    checkBoxPurpura(){
    
      this.setState({ checkPurpura: !this.state.checkPurpura,id:"purpura" });
    }
    checkBoxParty(){
    
      this.setState({ checkParty: !this.state.checkParty,id:"party" });
    }
    checkBoxMarriage(){
    
      this.setState({ checkMaarriage: !this.state.checkMaarriage,id:"marriage" });
    }

    aplicar(){
    
      if(this.state.id=="red"){
        alert("is red")
      }else if(this.state.id=="white"){
        alert("is white")
      }else if(this.state.id=="purpura"){
        alert("is purpura")
      }else if(this.state.id=="party"){
        alert("is party")
      }else if(this.state.id=="marriage"){
        alert("is marriage")
      }
      else if(this.state.id=="red" && this.state.id=="marriage"){
        alert("is red and marriage")
      }
  
    }
    
  render() {
  

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>RED</Text>
      <CheckBox value={this.state.checkRed} onChange={()=>this.checkBoxRed()}/>
      <Text>WHITE</Text>
      <CheckBox value={this.state.checkWhite} onChange={()=>this.checkBoxWhite()}/>
      <Text>PURPURA</Text>
      <CheckBox value={this.state.checkPurpura} onChange={()=>this.checkBoxPurpura()}/>
      <Text>PARTY</Text>
      <CheckBox value={this.state.checkParty} onChange={()=>this.checkBoxParty()}/>
      <Text>MARRIAGE</Text>
      <CheckBox value={this.state.checkMaarriage} onChange={()=>this.checkBoxMarriage()}/>

      <Button title="aplicar" onPress={() =>this.aplicar()}></Button>
    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are setting the state.id variable each time you toggle a checkbox state. Therefore, the state.id just will hold the last value.

```js
    checkBoxMarriage(){
      this.setState({ checkMaarriage: !this.state.checkMaarriage, id:"marriage" /* see here */ });
    }
```

Then, you tried to compare that single variable to be equal to two different values simultaneously.

```
   else if(this.state.id=="red" && this.state.id=="marriage"){ // <-- this will never happen
     alert("is red and marriage")
   }
```

So, at a first glance, I don't think you need the id variable. You just should compare using the checkbox state variables like this:

```js
   aplicar(){
      if(this.state.checkRed){
        alert("is red")
      }else if(this.state.checkWhite){
        alert("is white")
      }else if(this.state.checkPurpura){
        alert("is purpura")
      }else if(this.state.checkParty){
        alert("is party")
      }else if(this.state.checkMaarriage){
        alert("is marriage")
      }
      else if(this.state.checkRed && this.state.checkMaarriage){
        alert("is red and marriage")
      }
  
    }
```

Cheers!